# Knockout.js Change (not toggle) css class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I'm trying to manipulate of css class on knockout.js click event, but it's not working. Currently I'm binding css class basing on value of $data.IsSelected element (true | false). I can't get what is right way to do what I want - should I manipulate with DOM (as I'm trying to do now) or should I change value of observableArray element to be true instead of false, for example and then update ViewModel, so theoretically this must change css class.
Here is JS.

```
<script>
        function StyleViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.pref = ko.observableArray();
            self.img = ko.observableArray(["img/style1.png", "img/style2.png", "img/style3.png", "img/style4.png", "img/style5.png", "img/style6.png"]);
            self.toggle = function (data, event) {
                if (data.IsSelected == true) {  
                    //Here i'm trying to manipulate with DOM directly                 
                    $(event.target).closest("div").removeClass("txt-active").addClass("txt");
                    $(event.target).find("a.button").text("Добавить");
                }
                else {                 
                    $(event.target).removeClass("txt").addClass("txt-active");
                    $(event.target).find("div.txt-active > a.button").text("Добавлено");
                }
            }
            $.getJSON('/api/usersprofiles?userguid=' + $("#MainContent_guid").val(), self.pref);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new StyleViewModel());
            $("#go").click(function () {
                $("div.test-block").each(function () {
                    var style = $(this).find("h3").text();
                    var option = $(this).find("a").text();
                    var selected;
                    if (option == "Добавить") {
                        selected = false;
                    }
                    else if (option == "Добавлено") {
                        selected = true;
                    }
                    var json = "{'UserGUID':'" + $("#MainContent_guid").val() + "', 'Style':'" + style + "', 'Selected':'" + selected + "'}"
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: "/api/usersprofiles",
                        data: json,
                        success: function () { },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                            alert(err.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.replace("default.aspx");
                }, 3000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this it HTML to show binding:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="guid" />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Вкусы</h2>
            <p>Что вам по душе?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="styles" data-bind="foreach: pref">
            <div class="test-block" data-bind="click: $root.toggle">
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $data.Id" />
                <div class="bigshadowtest">
                    <img alt="" src="img/bigshadow.png">
                </div>
                <div data-bind="css: $data.IsSelected == true ? 'txt-active' : 'txt'">
                    <h3 data-bind="text: $data.name"></h3>
                    <a href="#" class="button" data-bind="text: $data.IsSelected == true ? 'Добавлено' : 'Добавить'"></a>
                </div>
                <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: $root.img }">
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="info" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <a href="#" id="go" class="gobtn">Поехали!</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

P.S. Here is one more problem - I can't bind observableArray self.img to the corresponding img element.

Comment: Is `IsSelected` an observable? I don't see where it's value is changed depending on the selection? I think you want it to change when the div is clicked, so in the toggle function just toggle the selected value and the bindings will do their work, given `IsSelected` is an observable.

Comment: No, IsSelected is one of the elements in observableArray. For example: {"$id":"1","name":"Стритстайл","IsSelected":true} @manji, could you please explain what you mean with some code?

Comment: Take a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U7PKDynWAdl0kEiZuCka?p=preview). As for the images, the src attribute expects a string but you're giving an observableArray. You maybe want to assign an image depending on the pref, so use the knockout `$index` observbale that contains the current foreach loop index (already done in the plunkr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your observable array's elements observable. With [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), so that your isSelected will be an observable and reflects it's value change to the ui.

Change your getJson method (untested code)

---

```
$.getJSON('/api/usersprofiles?userguid=' + $("#MainContent_guid").val(), function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.pref);
});
```

---

Or instead of using the mapping plugin u can create a new pref object and bind the data from server to that in a loop and push them into the observableArray. This way is more controllable then using mapping plugin.

```
    var oPref = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        self.IsSelected = ko.observable(data.IsSelected);
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        self.imgLink = ko.observable(data.imgLink);

        self.toggle = function () {
            if (self.IsSelected()) self.IsSelected(false);
            else self.IsSelected(true);
        }
    }

        function StyleViewModel() {
            var dataFromServer = [ 
                { Id: 1, IsSelected: false, name: "name1", imgLink: "img/style1.png" },
                { Id: 2, IsSelected: false, name: "name2", imgLink: "img/style2.png" },
                 { Id: 3, IsSelected: false, name: "name3", imgLink: "img/style3.png" }]

            var self = this;

            self.pref = ko.observableArray();

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(dataFromServer, function(item) { self.pref.push(new oPref(item)); });
        }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new StyleViewModel());
    });
```

And your html should be like follows

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="guid" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
         <h2>Вкусы</h2>

        <p>Что вам по душе?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="styles" data-bind="foreach: pref">
        <div class="test-block" data-bind="click: toggle">
            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id" />
            <div class="bigshadowtest">
                <img alt="" src="img/bigshadow.png">
            </div>
            <div data-bind="css: { 'txt-active': IsSelected(), 'txt': IsSelected() == false }">
                 <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
 <a href="#" class="button" data-bind="text: (IsSelected() == true ? 'Добавлено' : 'Добавить')"></a>

            </div>
            <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: imgLink }">
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="info" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <a href="#" id="go" class="gobtn">Поехали!</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide example please?

Comment: A note, if you make the IsSelected an observable. $data.IsSelected == true will not work due to $data.IsSelected being a function. you should use $data.IsSelected() == true instead.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example. I'm afraid that you got me wrong. This value (true or false) first time I'm really get from server, but when I change css class, I'm just changing this to opposite value e.g.  if (data.IsSelected == true) {  set element to false }.

Comment: @andrey.shedko if you can make isSelected observable and in toggle function just change the value of isSelected like data.IsSelected(false); the css will change too according to the rules you defined on ui.